# Замена символа в строке по его количеству

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Код ниже (c# winforms net4.0 vs2010) считает количество повторений символа "Environment.NewLine" в строке "Str". Подскажите пожалуйста, как выполнить следующее: в строке "Str" заменить каждый пятый символ "Environment.NewLine" на пробел. Количество повторений символа "Environment.NewLine" в строке "Str" может быть любое.

Пример:
было:

```
Str = текст + Environment.NewLine + текст + Environment.NewLine + текст + Environment.NewLine + текст + Environment.NewLine + текст + Environment.NewLine + текст + Environment.NewLine ...
```

должно стать:

```
Str = текст + Environment.NewLine + текст + Environment.NewLine + текст + Environment.NewLine + текст + Environment.NewLine + текст + " " + текст + Environment.NewLine ...
```

Спасибо заранее!

```
Str = Str + '"' + searchString + '"' + Environment.NewLine;
if (Str != "")
{
  int count = 0;
  foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(Str, Environment.NewLine))
    count++;

  if (count > 1)
  {
    ????
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вам такое решение? Делить строку, а потом с помощью Linq сделать то что нам нужно.

```
        var str = $"{Environment.NewLine} 1{Environment.NewLine}2{Environment.NewLine}3{Environment.NewLine}4{Environment.NewLine}5{Environment.NewLine}6{Environment.NewLine}7{Environment.NewLine}8{Environment.NewLine}9{Environment.NewLine}10{Environment.NewLine}11{Environment.NewLine}";
        // str = "\r\n 1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4\r\n5\r\n6\r\n7\r\n8\r\n9\r\n10\r\n11\r\n"
        var splitted = str.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string result = string.Empty;

        while(splitted.Any())
        {
            result += string.Join(Environment.NewLine, splitted.Take(5));
            splitted = splitted.Skip(5).ToArray();
        }
        // result = "\r\n 1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n45\r\n6\r\n7\r\n8\r\n910\r\n11\r\n"
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 1):

Раз речь пошла про LINQ :)

```
var res = input.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select((x, i) => (x, i))
    .GroupBy(x => x.i / 5)
    .Select(x => (x.Key, string.Join(Environment.NewLine, x.OrderBy(z=>z.i).Select(z=>z.x))))
    .Aggregate(string.Empty, (a, c)=>a + " " + c.Item2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если уж идти по тому пути что ты начала:

```
        var Str = "";
        var strArr = Str.ToArray();

        var matches = Regex.Matches(Str, Environment.NewLine);

        for (int i = 0; i <= matches.Count; i+=5)
        {
            var origStrIndex = matches[i].Index;

            strArr[origStrIndex] = ' ';
        }
        Str = new String(strArr);
```

но я не уверен сработает ли с символом переноса строки (это может быть 2 символа....)

Я бы советовал, наверное, все же использовать Regex.Replace как в примере вот здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47200835/replace-nth-regex-match-occurrence-in-string

Comment: Если считать, что `Environment.NewLine` занимает 1 символ, то непонятно, зачем тут Regex. Если же считать, что он может занимать больше 1 символа, то вот это `strArr[origStrIndex] = ' ';` будет некорректно

Comment: именно потому я и кинул линку на более правильный путь)

Comment: И именно потому я и написал что не уверен сработает ли с символом переноса строки винде

Comment: Да, вы обновили ответ пока я писал коммент и я этого не заметил :)

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример как это можно сделать без регулярок

```
string Replace5thNewLine(string input)
{
    var newLineArr = Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray();
    var originalLine = input.ToCharArray(); 

    var newLineCount = 0;
    var ret = new StringBuilder();

    for(var i=0; i<originalLine.Length; i++)
    {
        int j=0; 
        while((j+i)<originalLine.Length && j<newLineArr.Length && originalLine[j+i] == newLineArr[j]) j++;
        var isNewLine = j == newLineArr.Length;     
        if (isNewLine) newLineCount++;

        if (isNewLine && newLineCount % 5 == 0)
        {
            ret.Append(' ');
            i+=newLineArr.Length - 1;
        }
        else 
            ret.Append(originalLine[i]);
    }

    return ret.ToString();
}
```